# differences between scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr and scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr

Tags: scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Does anybody know when is better to choose which? They seem the same to me...

[lsmr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr)
[lsqr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both packages do the same. LSMR is based on Fong & Saunders algorithm from 2010 (see [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0758)), and has been introduced in scipy very recently (ie, version 0.10 and earlier won't have it). According to the paper, LSMR should converge faster than LSQR, which uses the Paige & Saunders algorithm that has been around for almost 30 years.